# Set bandwidth limit on chromebook (chrome os)

Tags: networking, google-chrome, router, bandwidth, google-chrome-os

I would like to set a GLOBAL limit on the amount of internet bandwidth that a Chromebook can use. I am aware that chrome's dev tools allow you to simulate a device with a slower internet connection, but I do not see a global setting. (As far as I can tell, throttling via chrome's dev tools has to be applied manually to each and every tab.)

Unfortunately, my router does not have any user-configurable QoS/traffic shaping capabilities, and I would prefer not to buy a new router.

EDIT: Ron Maupin points out that I can't exactly control the rate at which the router delivers data to the chromebook, and he's right. But what I had in mind is imposing an artificial bottleneck so that TCP congestion control will cause the sender to adjust their transmission rate. I'm not concerned about UDP traffic.

Comment: Do you meant outbound to the Internet traffic, or inbound from the Internet traffic? You really have no control over inbound traffic. If your router did support QoS, you could limit inbound traffic delivered to the device from the router, but by the time your router sees the traffic, the bandwidth has already been used.

Comment: What I had in mind is imposing an artificial bottleneck so that TCP congestion control will cause the sender to adjust their transmission rate. I'm not concerned about UDP traffic.

Comment: That is a pretty crude way to do it. You can't get a precise bandwidth restriction, and you will need to do a lot of trial-and-error to get close to your bandwidth goal, and the limit will vary based on other factors, e.g. SRTT, which can be different for different devices on the Internet.

Comment: Did you find anything for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the chrome://flags URL, there is the following global setting:

- Override effective connection type

  > Overrides the effective connection type of the current connection returned by the network quality estimator. Slow 2G on Cellular returns Slow 2G when connected to a cellular network, and the actual estimate effective connection type when not on a cellular network. Previews are usually served on 2G networks. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

**References**

- [Network Information API](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/)
- [chrome/browser/flag_descriptions.cc - chromium/src - Git at Google](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/flag_descriptions.cc)
- [Debugging problems with the network proxy - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy)